# Is it possible to add a reference to NetCore library from a NetCore app without using the same solution?

Tags: .net-core

I have a netstandard1.6 Project "MyLibrary"

I have a netcoreapp1.0 Project "MyApplication"

I have to reference "MyLibrary" from "MyApplication", without having those on the same solution.

Is it possible? How?

It's really confusing how DNX RC1 jumped into what Asp .Net 5 is right now, I can't seem to get going with it, I've read several articles and no documentation answered those questions to me.

Comment: You can point to he output (.DLL).

Comment: BTW, if you're reading some documentation that talks about ASP.NET 5, then it's probably outdated. It's called ASP.NET Core now.

Comment: As of today, netcore readopted msbuild and csproj, this question became completely obsolete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With .Net Core, there are two ways to reference dependencies:

1. Reference another project in the "solution", where the solution is specified by a [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/global-json) file.

   For example, the relevant part of your project.json could look like this:

   ```
   "dependencies": {
     "MyLibrary": { "target": "project" }
   }
   ```
2. Reference a NuGet package from a known package source. Package source can be either web-based (like nuget.org), or it can be a directory. You can configure known package sources either locally or globally using a [nuget.config](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file) file.

   Example project.json excerpt:

   ```
   "dependencies": {
     "MyLibrary": "1.0.0"
   }
   ```

For you, this means you have two options:

1. Add the library project to your "solution" by including it in your global.json.
2. Produce a NuGet package from your library (you can use `dotnet pack` for that), place it into a package source (probably just a directory) and configure that package source in a nuget.config file.

Comment: Yes! I've got it to work. I've compiled the code normally and ran `dotnet pack`, moved a nupkg file from bin folder to a local nuget repository I configured in Visual Studio in `Tools\Options\NuGet Package Manager`, then in `Manage NuGet Packages`, my repository could be found there, the library was also there as a package to install, `Restore packages` worked as intended and the external code could be used ok.
Tyvm for the help, I was used to just `Add Reference`, finding a .dll and done, now I know how referencing work in .Net Core projects.